# How to change the motd on a Linux distribution that has no /etc/motd ?

Tags: etc, motd

I have seen a simple tutorial on how to put ascii art in the /etc/motd in order to show it each time the PC starts as the message of the day. Unfortunately Linux Mint Rebecca does not have a /etc/motd. I created the file /etc/motd put ascii art inside, but this did not work.

Comment: You have to install [update-motd](http://community.linuxmint.com/software/view/update-motd) and manipulate files in /etc/update-motd.d/ directory.